# Is it always necessary to make hash table number of buckets a prime number for performance reason?

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable, associative-array

https://www.quora.com/Why-should-the-size-of-a-hash-table-be-a-prime-number?share=1

I see that people mention that the number of buckets of a hash table is better to be prime numbers.

Is it always the case? When the hash values are already evenly distributed, there is no need to use prime numbers then?

https://github.com/rui314/chibicc/blob/main/hashmap.c

For example, the above hash table code does not use prime numbers as the number of buckets.

https://github.com/rui314/chibicc/blob/main/hashmap.c#L37

But the hash values are generated from strings using `fnv_hash`.

https://github.com/rui314/chibicc/blob/main/hashmap.c#L17

So there is a reason why it makes sense to use bucket sizes that are not necessarily prime numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "usually you don't need a table whose size is a prime number, but there are some implementation reasons why you might want to do this."

Fundamentally, hash tables work best when hash codes are spread out as close to uniformly at random as possible. That prevents items from clustering in any one location within the table. At some level, provided that you have a good enough hash function to make this happen, the size of the table doesn't matter.

So why do folks say to pick tables whose size is a prime? There are two main reasons for this, and they're due to specific cases that don't arise in all hash tables.

One reason why you sometimes see prime-sized tables is due to a specific way of building hash functions. You can build reasonable hash functions by picking functions of the form h(x) = (ax + b) mod p, where a is a number in {1, 2, ..., p-1} and b is a number in the {0, 1, 2, ..., p-1}, assuming that p is a prime. If p isn't prime, hash functions of this form don't spread items out uniformly. As a result, if you're using a hash function like this one, then it makes sense to pick a table whose size is a prime number.

The second reason you see advice about prime-sized tables is if you're using an open-addressing strategy like quadratic probing or double hashing. These hashing strategies work by hashing items to some initial location k. If that slot is full, we look at slot (k + r) mod T, where T is the table size and r is some offset. If that slot is full, we then check (k + 2r) mod T, then (k + 3r) mod T, etc. If the table size is a prime number and r isn't zero, this has the nice, desirable property that these indices will cycle through all the different positions in the table without ever repeating, ensuring that items are nicely distributed over the table. With non-prime table sizes, it's possible that this strategy gets stuck cycling through a small number of slots, which gives less flexibility in positions and can cause insertions to fail well before the table fills up.

So assuming you aren't using double hashing or quadratic probing, and assuming you have a strong enough hash function, feel free to size your table however you'd like.

Comment: So in the hashmap implementation in chibicc, it is OK to leave the number of buckets to be non-prime numbers?

Comment: My read on that table is that it's using linear probing, which does not require a prime-sized hash table. So no, there's no requirement that the table size be a prime.

Answer (score 0):

templatetypedef has some excellent points as always - just adding a couple more and some examples...

> Is it always necessary to make hash table number of buckets a prime number for performance reason?

No.  Firstly, using prime numbers for bucket count tends to mean you need to spend more CPU cycles to fold/mod a hash value returned by the hash function into the current bucket count.  A popular alternative is to use powers of two for the bucket count (e.g. 8, 16, 32, 64... as you resize), because then you can do a bitwise AND operation to map from a hash value to a bucket in 1 CPU cycle.  ***That*** answers your *"So there is a reason why it makes sense to use bucket sizes that are not necessarily prime numbers?"*

Tuning a hash table for performance often means weighing the cost of a stronger hash function and modding by prime numbers against the cost of higher collisions.

Prime bucket counts often help reduce collisions when the hash function is unable to produce a very good distribution for the keys its fed.

For example, if you hashed a bunch of pointers to 64-bit `double`s using an identity hash (basically, casting the pointer address to a `size_t`), then the hash values would all be multiples of 8 (due to alignment), and if you had a hash table size like say 1024 or 2048 (powers of 2), then all your pointers would hash onto 1/8th of the bucket indices (specifically, buckets 0, 8, 16, 25, 32 etc.).  With a prime number of buckets, at least the pointer values - which if the load factor is high are inevitably spread out over a much larger range than the range of bucket indices - tend to wrap around the hash table hitting different indices.

When you use a very strong hash function - where the low order bits are effectively random but repeatable, you'll already get a good distribution across buckets regardless of the bucket count.  There are also times when even with a terribly weak hash function - like an identity hash - `h(x) == x` - all the bits in the keys are so random that they produce as good a distribution as a cryptographic hash could produce, so there's no point spending extra time on a stronger hash - that may even increase collisions.

There a also times when the distribution isn't inherently great, but you can afford to use extra memory to keep the load factor low, so it's not worth using primes or a better hash function.  Still, extra buckets puts more strain on the CPU caches too - so things can end up slower than hoped for.

Other times, keys with an identity hash have an inherent tendency to fall into distinct buckets (e.g. because they might have been generated by an incrementing counter, even if some of the values are no longer in use).  In that case, a strong hash function increases collisions and worsens CPU cache access patterns.  Whether you use powers of two or prime bucket counts makes little difference here.

> When the hash values are already evenly distributed, there is no need to use prime numbers then?

That statement is trivially true but kind of pointless if you're talking about hash values after the mod-to-current-hash-table-size operation: even distribution there directly relates to few collisions.

If you're talking about the more interesting case of hash values evenly distributed in the hash function return type value space (e.g. a 64-bit integer), before those values are modded into whatever the current hash table bucket count is, then there's till room for prime numbers to help, but only when the hashed key space a larger range than the hash bucket indices.  The pointer example above illustrated that: if you had say 800 distinct 8-byte-aligned pointers going into ~1000 bucket, then the difference between the numerically lowest pointer and the higher address would be at least 799*8 = 6392... you're wrapping around the table more than 6 times *at a minimum* (for close-as-possible pointers), and a prime number of buckets would increase the odds of each of "wrap" modding onto previously unused buckets.

Note that some of the above benefits to prime bucket counts apply to any kind of collision handling - separate chaining, linear probing, quadratic probing, double hashing, cuckoo hashing, robin hood hashing etc.